# How can I make sure Google's "Find My Phone" works when my phone is in power saving mode?

Tags: google, samsung-galaxy-s-10

I recently couldn't find my phone, so I used Google's Find My Phone web app to try to locate it. The service couldn't locate my phone, and though I'm not quite sure why (there are a sea of settings), my guess is because it was in low power mode (and not connected to WiFi).

My phone is a Galaxy S10e. What settings should I use to make sure Google Find My Phone can find my phone even in "low power mode"?

I know how to set special app permissions and give them usage of background data even in low power and/or mobile data mode. I'm just not sure which app to give the permission too.